# Replace only numbers in the text, not the tag addresses

Tags: php, replace, numbers, persian

Please guide me go, I just want inner tag change, not the attribute of tag

```
$string = '
    <p> 

    <a href="http://example.com/news/1234"> 
        1234 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </a> 
    <img src="http://images.example.com/news/1458129660ir27_300x210.jpg" alt="photo 1234"> 

    </p>';
```

to

```
<p> 

    <a href="http://example.com/news/1234"> 
        ۱۲۳۴ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </a> 
    <img src="http://images.example.com/news/1458129660ir27_300x210.jpg" alt="photo ۱۲۳۴"> 

    </p>
```

my code : Replaces all the numbers, but I'd just replace the text numbers

```
public function CEF($string) {
            $persian = array('۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹');
            $num = range(0, 9);
            return str_replace($num,$persian, $string);
        }

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

Comment: You won't do that with str_raplace. You need preg_replace and the correct regular expression to match just the numbers out of the tags.

Comment: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in test.php on line 21

Comment: Saeid, please do not dump codes in the comments, update the original post with the codes.

Comment: I just need a pattern when each number individually replaced with preg_replace like I just change the text